# Get a frequency and show a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I've to catch a frequency and after I've to show a view controller. To get the frequency I used the [pitch detector](https://github.com/irtemed88/PitchDetector). I'm getting the frequency but when I try to run the app, it crash when it should load the view controller. I post the code I wrote:

```
- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency {
    frequencyRecived = newFrequency;
    NSLog(@"%f", frequencyRecived);
    if (frequencyRecived > 18000) {
        [self.imageListening.layer removeAllAnimations];
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        GameViewController *controller = (GameViewController*)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"game"];
        [self stopListener];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

It crash exactly in row `[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];` and Xcode says this:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x14e5de30: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   0x366036fb WebThreadLock
2   0x30e1e6a3 <redacted>
3   0x30f46a69 <redacted>
4   0x31015171 <redacted>
5   0x31015111 <redacted>
6   0x31014e87 <redacted>
7   0x30e94a4f <redacted>
8   0x31015171 <redacted>
9   0x31014e87 <redacted>
10  0x30f70607 <redacted>
11  0x31015171 <redacted>
12  0x31015111 <redacted>
13  0x31014e87 <redacted>
14  0x30f6fdd9 <redacted>
15  0x30ec862b <redacted>
16  0x30d24bed <redacted>
17  0x30c0530d <redacted>
18  0x30c05289 <redacted>
19  0x30cae937 <redacted>
20  0x30ceb4b3 <redacted>
21  0x30ce9deb <redacted>
22  0x30ce8e55 <redacted>
23  0xcf783 -[ViewController frequencyChangedWithValue:]
24  0xd11f7 RenderFFTCallback(void*, unsigned long*, AudioTimeStamp const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, AudioBufferList*)
25  0x2dda569f <redacted>
26  0x2dd944eb <redacted>
27  0x2dd955d9 <redacted>
28  0x2dd8bdff <redacted>
29  0x2dcf9899 <redacted>
30  0x2dd68889 <redacted>
31  0x2dd94809 <redacted>
```

I used the code in another app and it works great, what's wrong in my code, why it shows me this issue? I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the frequencyChangedWithValue method being called?

The error says that you are not invoking it from the main thread or the webview thread. Are you detecting the pitch in a background thread?

You can try:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(presentationWrapper:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and wrap the present modal view controller:

```
- (void) presentationWrapper:(GameViewController *) controller {
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code is not executed on main thread. Try presenting using dispatching to the main thread

```
 - (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency {
    frequencyRecived = newFrequency;
    NSLog(@"%f", frequencyRecived);
    if (frequencyRecived > 18000) {
        [self stopListener];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.imageListening.layer removeAllAnimations];
            UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            GameViewController *controller = (GameViewController*)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"game"];
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        });  
    }
}
```

Comment: had the same situation. This solution works perfectly.